# Using multiple jQuery plugins on multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have site which is using a few JavaScript/jQuery plugins, I then have a `default.js` file which uses the plugin functionality for each of the different pages.

E.g. some plugins I have include:

- a custom scrollbar plugin
- a slideshow plugin
- a cookie plugin
- etc.

Then in the `default.js` file, I'll do something as follows (pseudocode):

```
var scrolling = findScrollbarDiv;
scrolling.ScrollFunction({ options });
```

(and then the same for the slideshow + other plugins I have)

However, if there is a plage where `findScrollbarDiv` returns null, I get an error something like the following:

> ScrollFunction is not a function

This is not because the elements are returning null, but because I haven't included the plugin file for this page. My reasoning behind this is that I don't want to include every file on every page (even if it's not needed) as this could cause unnecessary HTTP requests (especially on the homepage, which only needs one plugin)

This error in turn messes up the rest of the JavaScript.

What is the best way to overcome this? Should I just include every plugin file on every page regardless of whether it is needed or not? Or is there some JavaScript like the following that I can use:

```
var scrolling = findScrollbarDiv;
if(scrolling != null) {
    scrolling.ScrollFunction({ options });
}
```

(this feels a bit clunky to me, but if this is the best solution let me know)

Or is using one default js file to launch all plugins a bad idea?

Comment: You say you don't want to include it where it's not required. It's clearly required in this case so include it. If `scrolling` isn't meant to be assigned on this page then checking for null is fine.

Comment: If your only worry is the needed HTTP requests, you could easily combine all the plugins/jQuery itself to one single file (which you can GZIP and compress). This way, you'll get one single HTTP request for everything.

Comment: I've thought about the one file solution, but I'd rather keep them separate for maintainability. My other worry is that even with combining/compressing/gzipping the file would still be pretty big + any change in the file would invalidate the use cache (as opposed to just invalidating the cache for one file)

Comment: You're probably right though, that may be the best solution speed wise

Comment: have a look at [http://requirejs.org/](http://requirejs.org/) it will do all the magic in the background and load all the requierd modules for you without adding them to the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same header file and you don't mind having the file included, you can always check if the element exists before attaching an event to it.

Heres an example:

```
if(jQuery('#someElement').length > 0){
    jQuery('#someElement').ScrollFunction({ options });
}
```

Either that, or have a JavaScript file for each function.

So you'd have one for the gallery and one for the cookies etc.. And include only the ones necessary for each page.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but on reflection it appears the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it as a conditional statement and avoid the clunky if:

```
scrolling && scrolling.ScrollFunction({ options });
```

This works great for any method you want to call and want to check if the parent object exists before you do.
You can go further (if you need to) and check if the method itself exists before execution:

```
scrolling && scrolling.ScrollFunction && scrolling.ScrollFunction({ options });
```

if scrolling is a collection, just check it's length (if length == 0 the statement will fail):

```
scrolling.length && scrolling.ScrollFunction({ options });
```